# Asp.net connecting my login page to my godaddy sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a login for my website I use the log in system from visual studio 2012 but when I try to go live and connect my live database I am gating a error

Server Error in '/' Application.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: Are you able to connect to the DB using sql client?

Comment: I am using this database for all data on the site successful  but for to login I am not able to connect I am gating the error message